# Is there some good references of the method Median of Means Estimator?

Tags: references, estimators, median, analysis-of-means

I can't find the term in Wikipedia, and by searching online, I seem to know the original material raised up the idea *Median of Means Estimator* is [this book](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/Nemirovskii_Yudin_1983.pdf), while I can only find the scanned edition of this book, so I can't directly search the keywords, and the content seems doesn't offer more useful information where *Median of Means Estimator* might be raised.

I mainly want to know *one theorem* which is related to the Median of means estimator, which I read in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08953)(Theorem S1 near Eq. (S13) ) is different from the little things I found online. I stated the theorem below for convenient reference:

> Let $X$ be a random variable with variance $\sigma^2$. Then, $K$ independent sample means of size $N=34\sigma^2/\epsilon^2$ suffice to construct a median of means estimator $\hat{\mu}(N,K)$ that obeys $Pr[|\hat{\mu}-\mathbb{E}[X]|\ge\epsilon]\le2e^{-K/2}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So is there some formal statement and proof of this kind of theorem of Median of Means Estimator?

Comment: It is always annoying when there is a reference to a book without specification of the page or section. With some googling you can find out that it is page 243 from the book. However, I can't help you much further. While the book is a translation into English, the mathematics reads like Russian to me. (See several articles that link to page 243 https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=nemirovsky+"median+of+means"+"p.+243")

Comment: The inequality is obviously not holding for every $\epsilon\ge 0$...

Comment: @Xi'an why not? There is dependence of $N$ on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first paper cited below includes a review and proof of the median-of-means estimator. The second paper (whose main goal is to show an optimal sample size for mean estimation) also mentions this estimator (near end of section 2.1).

REFERENCES:

- Devroye, L., Lerasle, M., et al. "Sub-Gaussian mean estimators", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.05845.pdf
- Kunsch, R.J., Novak, E. And Rudolf, D., 2019. Solvable integration problems and optimal sample size selection. Journal of Complexity, 53, pp.40-67.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short approximate derivation

For a single sample mean  $X_N$ you have the Chebyshev's inequality

$$P(\vert X_N -\mu_X \vert \geq k\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt{N}}) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

or

$$P(\vert X_N -\mu_X \vert \geq \epsilon ) \leq \frac{\sigma_X^2}{N\epsilon^2} = \frac{1}{34}$$

The last equality stems from setting $N=34\sigma_X^2/\epsilon^2$.

The probability for the median of a sample of $K$ variables to be outside some range is less probable than the probability of at least half of the individual $K$ variables being outside the range. This is because the latter is a necessary requirement for the former.

This is similar to $P(Y \geq  (K-1)/2 )$ if $K$ is odd, or $P(Y \geq  K/2 )$ if $K$ is even, with $Y \sim Binom (p = 1/34, n = K)$.

This can be expressed with some [limits for the tail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) of a binomial distribuion

**Hoeffding's inequality**

$$P(Y \geq (K-1)/2) \leq \text{exp}\left(- 2K\left(\frac{33}{34} - \frac{(K-3)/2}{K}\right)^2\right) =\text{exp} \left(- 2K \left(\frac{16}{34}  -1.5/K\right)^2 \right) \approx \text{exp} \left(- 0.44 N + 2.82 - 2.25/N \right) \approx 16.84 \text{exp} \left(- 0.44 N  \right)  $$

This is not exactly $2 \text{exp}\left(-0.5 K  \right)$ and less tight.

**With Chernoff bound**

$$P(Y \geq (K-1)/2) \approx P(Y \geq K/2+1) \leq \text{exp}\left(- K (0.5 \log(0.5 \cdot 34)+0.5 \log(0.5 \cdot 34 /33)) \right)  \approx \text{exp}\left(- 1.085 K  \right) $$

this is a tighter bound than $2 \text{exp}\left(-0.5 K  \right)$

---

Simulations show that this tighter bound is not unreasonable.

Comment: In going from your first equation to the second, what happened to the variable k? I am having trouble seeing where the factor of 34 comes in.

Comment: @SurgicalCommander use $\epsilon = k \frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{N}}$ or $k = \frac{\sqrt{N}}{\epsilon \sigma_x}$

Comment: I don't remember why the factor is 34. I believe that I just took it for granted and derived the inequalities with it (I did not succeed and got different inequalities).

Answer (score 2):

If you carry on just a bit further (remarks to theorem 1), they attest to intentionally picking a less tight bound as a worst case...

You can get a tighter bound from [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/short_note/note_MoM.pdf) from Proposition 1,

${\rm Pr}(|\hat{\mu}-\mu| > \epsilon) \leq \exp{\left\{-2K\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sigma^2}{N \epsilon^2}\right)^2\right\}} \leq 2\exp{\left\{-K/2\right\}} \leq \delta/M$

for finite $\sigma^2$ and for some $K=2\log(2M/\delta)$ for $1 \geq \delta \geq 0$

Comment: How did you get the second inequality? The exponent is $2(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sigma^2}{N\epsilon^2})^2 = 0.44 < 1/2$